# Sequelize performs extra SELECT query before updating associations

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, associations

Sequelize seems to introduce unnecessary queries when adding new associated record to a source record.

For example, consider a regular many-to-many association with a Users model and a Groups model, where a user `belongsToMany` groups, and each group `belongsToMany` users.

If I create a new user record, then add two existing groups to that user, Sequelize executes what seems to be an extra unnecessary

SELECT` query:

```js
const record = await Users.create({id: 1, name: 'John'})
await record.addGroups([2,3]);
```

The above call to `record.addGroups([2,3])` leads to these two MySQL queries:

```
SELECT group_id
     , user_id
     , 
  FROM user_groups
 WHERE user_groups.user_id = 1
   AND user_groups.group_id IN ('2', '3');

INSERT INTO user_groups (group_id,user_id) VALUES 
('2','1'),('3','1');
```

---

1) What is the cause of the first `SELECT` query above?

2) Are there any benefits including that query?

3) Are there any ways to disable this extra `SELECT` query?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your SELECT query is invalid; not sure what else we can say

Comment: I suppose a SELECT is used to check if records already exist and if they exist then do not try to insert new ones. Try to insert them twice and see what SQL-queries will be executed.